# Why do I instinctively want to use the present tense with a conditional?

Tags: grammaticality, future, conditionals

My boss is not a native speaker of English, so he often asks me to correct his writing. The problem is, he wants me to explain *why* I make changes, and doesn't accept "it just sounds better that way" as an answer. Usually, I come up with some likely-sounding <strike>nonsense</strike> reasoning, but this afternoon, I just couldn't articulate why I corrected his

> We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you will send us.

to

> We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you send us.

I know that the version with "will" is perfectly understandable, and I don't think it is ungrammatical *per se*; but it just sounds better without "will", and I'd like to know *why*.

Edit: the current highest-voted answer answers the question "why did my boss write it with a future tense". **I don't care about that.** That's **not** my question. I want to know **why the present tense sounds more natural**. Is there a "rule" about this? If it's not the subjunctive (since people keep downvoting the answer which says it is), what is it?

Comment: your boss is French?

Comment: @Louis: no, he's Hungarian.

Comment: From your comments and edit, it's not clear to me exactly what type of answer you're looking for in saying "why it sounds better". As I've tried to show in my answer, there's no inherent logic behind the choice, and it basically just "sounds better" because that's how native speakers usually form this type of sentence. Are you looking for a different answer than if you'd asked "Why does it sound better to say 'the cat sat' than 'sat the cat'"?

Comment: @Neil: I want an answer that I can cite for my boss. As I said, "it sounds better that way" (or other variations on "that's just the way it is") won't satisfy him.

Comment: Well, the pattern is that native English speakers generally don't use "will" in future-oriented subordinate clauses. The reason that they don't is that they don't. Your boss has asked you for your opinion as a native speaker and you've provided him with that opinion. If he then choses to ignore your opinion, that's kind of his funeral...

Comment: Or look at it this way: if your boss asked, "Why do people say 'he does' and not 'he dooog'?", what kind of answer would he be looking to 'satisfy' him that's fundamentally different from the nature of your answer?

Comment: The reason we don't say "he dooog" is that "dooog" is not a word. I think that's a pretty fundamental difference.

Comment: @Marthaª: In light of Barrie's answer, you might perhaps edit the question to clarify whether you already receive regular schedules from the client anyway. In which case, even if in fact you'll need *future* schedules to figure out the current issue, I think the precise meaning of "send" is different to if you haven't yet received any at all.

Comment: Well, apparently a bounty is a good way to go from *"a few answers, none of which seem correct"* to *"a dizzying array of plausibly-correct answers"* in a jiffy. :-)

Comment: @Martha: Very true. About the only thing I think I'm more sure of now is that the subjunctive isn't an issue here. Gnawme's answer in particular reminds me that the "future tense" is tricky to pin down in English.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your sentence as amended, *send* is without a doubt in the present indicative tense (and it is not a conditional sentence). In English, however, the present tense does rather more than express what’s going on in the present. To talk about something that’s going on right now, we generally use *be* + the *–ing* form of the verb which describes the action or state. We use the present tense, on the other hand, to refer to:

(1) a fact that is always or generally true (*Water boils at 100 degrees centigrade*);

(2) a repeated action (*I go to church every Sunday*);

(3) an event that occurs at the moment we are speaking (*I promise*); and

(4) fixed or planned events taking place in the future (*My flight leaves early tomorrow morning*).

In your example, *send* could express either (2) or (4), depending on the context. In either case, it is understood that the schedules are or will be sent according to a pre-arranged plan. If that were not to be the case, you would have to say *We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you’ll be sending us*. Perhaps that was what your boss meant. If so, he was half right, but we express the future by using *will* + the plain form of the verb only when we are making a prediction or when we are expressing a decision, often made at the time of speaking, about the immediate future. Neither of those cases seems likely given the first half of the sentence.

Comment: I think you are right. Without clarification from OP we can't rule out (2), which can still be logically valid even though the *particular* schedules which might resolve the problem haven't yet been sent (we only know that anyway because the boss originally used "will"). But if it's not (2), the justification centres on (4). Which OP would prefer because this superficially innocent "standard usage" politely/obliquely reminds the clients of their (presumably, pre-arranged) commitment to actually send the schedules.

Comment: +1 I think number (4) and the consequent analysis is right on the spot

Answer (score 21):

In trying to come up with some "reasoning" for your boss, I think you're likely to hit upon either a dead end or a an invented logic that is essentially a red herring. As in many cases, what you're dealing with is simply an arbitrary choice in how the language encodes something which indeed different languages arbitrarily encode in different ways.

English speakers don't tend to use "will" in subordinate clause in this cases (and so to a native English speaker it sounds unnatural to do so) whereas, say, French speakers would have a strong tendency to use a future tense in this case. Another example:

> English: As soon as you **arrive**, I will help you.
>
> French: Dès que vous **arriverez**, je vous aiderai. (Literally: As soon as you will arrive, I will help you.)

Other languages may encode this differently again. Spanish speakers, for example, would tend to use a present subjunctive in the subordinate clause:

> Spanish: En cuanto **llegues**, te ayudo. ("In as-much you-arrive-SUBJUNCTIVE, you I-help")

So you're trying to come up with some reasoning or logic for the arbitrary choice made in English. Does this mean that French is more or less "logical" to use a future tense? Is English more "logical" to use a simple present tense? Is Spanish more "logical" to use a present subjunctive?

Well, not really. Remember that names such as "present" and "future" are just arbitrary made-up labels. If we label as "present" a form actually used to denote a future action, then that's a fault of our labelling, not the language. Just because we've labelled a particular form as "present" doesn't then magically mean that the language will suddenly obey some expectation implied by our label.

What you're seeing are just arbitrary differences, of which you'll find all sorts of other examples if you cross-compare languages. And while you're struggling to invent some spurious reasoning as to why "will" is not used in future-oriented subordinate clauses in English, your French counterpart will be inventing some spurious reasoning as to why the future tense is absolutely necessary...

Comment: +1 for the relevant examples in your already good answer.

Comment: I think you're answering "why does my boss want to put a 'will' in there" rather than what I actually asked.

Comment: I don't think my boss' problem stems from a direct-translation error, because the way to say this in Hungarian would not necessarily use a future tense. And besides, **I don't care why the boss wrote it his way**; I want to know why I think my way sounds better.

Comment: Martha -- as I say in my answer, yours "sounds better" because you're more used to hearing subordinate clauses without the "will". My point of the comparison with other languages is to show that this is just an arbitrary accident of the language you happened to be born with: if you were a French speaker you'd be thinking that it "sounded better" to use a future tense etc.

Comment: It's hard to identify a cause for such arbitrary historical changes in language.  Often there isn't one; simply repeated reinforcement of an option that was selected by chance.  Of course if you really really want a reason we could probably "craft" one for you.  (Though the SE community might frown on knowingly incorrect responses...)

Answer (score 6):

> She'll be riding six white horses when she comes.

See [Wikipedia on Present Tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_tense)

There is a rule, namely

> If the future event is in a dependant clause then it's rendered in the
>   present tense.

Your correction 'sounds better' because it obeys this rule of grammar.  You can break this rule without loss of sense, but your boss's version *is* ungrammatical. It's a general fact about [dependant clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balancing_and_deranking) that they obey different rules in relation to verbs than apply in main clauses.

I would be interested in counter-examples to this rule, if anyone can come up with one.

---

First counter examaple (simplified version of @Peter Shor's example below)

> There is a good chance that it will rain.

Is this really about a future event, or are we talking about the current forecast? I'm not sure.

Comment: Dr. Seuss book title: *Oh the places you'll go.* Here, you need to use the future tense to avoid ambiguity, and sure enough, you use it, and I think most native English speakers would agree with this usage. I can't articulate the exact rules, though. A more complicated example from inside the book: *And when you’re alone, there’s a very good chance you’ll meet things that scare you right out of your pants.* Here, there are two dependent clauses with *you'll meet* (future) and *scare you* (present). The second one could be future, though, without sounding strange.

Comment: @cindy: It's a dependent clause; *there is a very good chance* is the main clause. Expanding the contractions and adding the elided words, you get *When you are alone, there is a very good chance that you will meet things that scare you right out of your pants.* But the final clause *that scare you* is back in the present, even though it's clearly happening in the future.

Comment: Tense in relative clauses is not deranked. The sentence in the original post uses a relative clause; therefore, future tense is expressed using...future tense! You're wrong. You're wrong. You're wrong.

Comment: I think this might not be 100% right, but it's not *wrong wrong wrong*. On the other hand, **That will depend on whether it will rain**, for example - that's *wrong*.

Answer (score 4):

You sometimes do need to use the future tense in dependent clauses.

> We need to review the sites you will visit in Venice.
>   *We need to review the sites you visit in Venice.

But you don't do it if the future is already implied by another verb in the sentence.

> Write to me and tell me all about the sites you visit in Venice.
>   *Write to me and tell me all about the sites you will visit in Venice.

(Actually, the last sentence sounds fine if you will be writing before you visit Venice.)

What I think is going on is that you use the future in the dependent clause only if the action in the dependent clause takes place considerably farther in the future than the action in the main clause. That is, you judge whether the tense in the dependent clause should be the present or the future by looking at the time of action *relative* to the action in the main clause. Consider:

> We will teach you everything you will ever need for your job.
>   *We will teach you everything you ever need for your job.

Here, you need to put the dependent clause in the future because it takes place in the indefinite future *after* being taught.

In your sentence,

> We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you send us,

the dependent clause clearly has to happen before the action in the main clause. Thus, you cannot put this dependent clause in the future.

For some additional examples, consider the following sentences:

> Go to Union Station, figure out which train will leave for New York at 4pm, and watch it to see whether Dr. X boards it.

The verb in first dependent clause (*will leave*) takes the future, because the train leaves *after* you find it. The verb in second dependent clause (*boards*) takes the present and cannot take the future, because he will be boarding it *while* you're watching it. You could instead say "which train leaves for New York at 4pm", but only because it's a habitual action—a train leaves for New York every day at 4pm. To see this, consider the sentence:

> Go to the garage, ask the attendant which car Dr. X will drive to New York, and leave this note on it.

Here, if you said "which car Dr. X drives to New York", you would be implying that he always drives the same car to New York.

You sometimes even have to use the past tense for dependent clauses that are set in the future, if they are in the past relative to the action in the main clause:

> Next Tuesday, go to the Grand Hotel, figure out which room Dr. X slept in on Monday night, and ransack its wastebaskets.

Dr. X sleeps *before* the action in the main clause, so you have to use the past tense.

The first conditional is a special case of this rule

> If his train comes on time, we will miss Dr. X at the station.

In a conditional sentence, the dependent clause almost always takes place at the same time or before the action in the main clause, so you cannot use the future in the dependent clause.

Answer (score 3):

The present tense sounds more 'natural' to you in this case because you know in your heart of hearts that the English language *has no future tense*.

(Don't argue with me; argue with linguists like [Geoff Pullum](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005471.html).)

As [this article](http://englishonthe.net/2009/02/10/english-has-no-future/) notes:

> We talk about the future all the time – how is that possible if there
>   is no tense for it?  Well, we get around it by using one of several
>   standard ways of speaking about future events, each one with its own
>   particular meaning.
>
> 1. WILL.  Do you think John will visit us this summer?
> 2. GOING TO.  I’m going to resign from my job.
> 3. PRESENT CONTINUOUS.  Manchester United are playing at Wembley
>      tonight.
> 4. SIMPLE PRESENT.  My flight leaves at 7.00 tonight.

The article makes these recommendations for when to use what:

> - For *predicting* — talking about what I think will happen in the    future, without any reference to the present, we use *will* or *going 
>     to*, but not the present continuous.
> - When we talk about *future plans* — things that have already been    decided, we use *going to* or present continuous, but not *will*.
> - When we talk about a future action *at the moment when we decide to    do it*, we use *will*.
> - When we have *present evidence* that something is going to happen    (that is, we can see it coming) we use *going to*.
> - When we talk about future events that are *already on a programme*,    such as a timetable, we can use *simple present*.
>
> This little summary doesn’t say everything there is to say about the
>   future, as there are some other forms that we can also use:
>
> 1. WILL BE + ING. Fred *will be having* dinner with us tomorrow.
> 2. TO BE TO. The President *is to* visit Florida later this month.
> 3. WILL HAVE + past participle (future perfect). The workmen *will have
>      replaced* all the windows by next Tuesday.

In the original sentence

> We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you will send
>   us.

the word *will* fits none of these usage cases particularly well:

- It's a certainty that you'll be sent the schedules, so *will* or
  *going to* don't fit in a predictive sense — although, see next point.
- You (or your boss) could argue for the correctness of "...the
  schedules you are *going to* send us" since their sending has already
  been decided.
- Sending the schedules wasn't decided at that moment, so *will* doesn't fit
  this case, either.
- Again, present evidence (you know the schedules are on their way) argues for the use of *going to*.
- Sending the schedules is already on the agenda, so your use of the simple present *send* is appropriate.

The last point explains why the present tense sounds more 'natural' — it's because it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Could it simply be that "We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you **will** send us." sounds as if you are giving an order?

After all, you would be more likely to write something like "Please send us the schedules" than "You **will** send us the schedules", which would be unnecessarily blunt even for business correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

I think omitting the *will* possibly implies general politeness. In a business context direct answers are preferred but learned speech and writing patterns convey conventions of nuance that imply different meanings to the recipient. If will is included then the recipient receives an ever so slightly stand-offish or authoritarian personality quality. If its not included its more polite and approachable.

With the many combinations of stress, intonation, tone, and context several semantic nuances can be conveyed. But of course this is a written document so the writing style should attempt to put any questions of tone and ulterior meaning to rest with the most polite yet direct way of communicating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're working from a false premise: 'the schedules you send us' is not present tense, though it looks like it. There are many ways to indicate the future in English besdies 'will'; for example "I am going to do it, but not until the cheque arrives", where both *going* and *arrives* look like present.  This 'send' is similarly future, as indicated by *might*, so adding 'will' sounds odd because it is tautologous (I think).

It may also matter whether the modal verb is 'may' or 'might'.  Your example sounds as if it should be "We may be able to figure it out... (but there are no guarantees)"  rather than "We might be able to figure it out... (but unfortunately the computer crashed yesterday)"; which did you (or he) intend?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the examples on [this page](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional.htm) (scroll down to "Various Tenses in the Conditional) answer your question.  Your scenario seems to mirror this example:

> *True as one-time future event*
>
> If + subject + present tense ||   subject + future tense
>
> If Judita hands in her paper early tomorrow, ||   she'll probably get an A.

In other words:

If you send us your schedules || we will probably be able to figure this out.

I know you worded it a little differently but I think the example still holds up, and explains why you'd use the present tense 'you send' rather than the future 'you will send'.

Comment: I don’t think conditional sentences are a good analogy here. A conditional sentence (the ‘First conditional’, as it happens) would be something like ‘If you send us the schedules, we might be able to figure this out from them.’ However, it could also be ‘If you will send us the schedules, we might be able to figure this out from them’ where ‘will’ indicates volition: ‘If you would be good enough . . .’

Answer (score 0):

In English, future more vivid conditionals are formed using this formula:

> "if" (or "when") + present indicative, (optional: "then" +) future indicative.

Although it seems logically odd, English forms this type conditional using the present indicative. All indicative conditionals in English follow a pattern except the future more vivid.

Indicative Conditionals:

> Future More Vivid: "if" + present indicative, (optional: "then" +) future indicative.
>   
> Present General: "if" + present indicative, (optional: "then" +) present indicative. 
>   
> Past General: "if" + past indicative, (optional: "then" +) past indicative.

You could rephrase the sentence written by your boss in this way, demonstrating more clearly the pieces of the conditional statement:

> When you send us the schedules, we might be able to figure this out

If you were to invert the sentence, its meaning would still be conveyed, but its tense and mood pattern would need to remain the same as such:

> We might be able to figure this out when you send us the schedules.

**Additional (and Very Important) Information Regarding Your Sentence:**

The sentence that you provided implies more connection between the schedules and the ability to figure this (whatever "this" may be) out, so the way that you phrased it works better, but you actually need to reevaluate your corrections. Since the sentence is *not* a conditional but uses a relative clause, your boss is actually correct in this instance.

> We might be able to figure this out from the schedules you will (or "are going to") send us.

You also might consider adding a relative pronoun to improve the sentence.

> We might be able to figure this out from the schedules *that* you are going to send us.

"That you will send us" is a relative clause acting as an adjective describing "schedules". Using relative pronouns is useful when introducing relative clauses.

**Additional Examples Clarifying Tense in Relative Clauses:**

Primary Sequence (present or future tense verb in the main clause):

> Simultaneous: The verb in the relative clause will be in the present indicative.
>   
> i.e. I give the book to a person who enjoys reading.
>   
> Completed: The verb in the relative clause will be in the perfect or imperfect indicative.
>   
> i.e. I give the book to a person who read another from the series.
>   
> Subsequent: The verb in the relative clause will be in the future indicative.
>   
> i.e. I give the book to a person who will read it.

Secondary Sequence (past tense in the main clause):

> Simultaneous: The verb in the relative clause will be in the perfect or imperfect indicative.
>   
> i.e. I gave the book to a person who enjoyed reading.
>   
> Completed: The verb in the relative clause will be in the pluperfect indicative.
>   
> i.e. I gave the book to a person who had read another from the series.
>   
> Subsequent: The verb in the relative clause will use the simple conditional.
>   
> i.e. I gave the book to a person who would read it.

**The answer to your question is that it possibly sounds more natural to use the present indicative in place of the future indicative because this is how English would form it if it were a conditional, and this particular sentence can easily be rephrased as a conditional statement rather than a simple sentence containing an adjectival relative clause.**

Comment: I believe the rules for conditionals in English are a special case of the rules for relative clauses, which require the use of the present in this sentence.

Comment: PeterShor, The rules for sequence of tenses in conditionals in English are not "a special case of the rules for relative clauses" as conditional statements are not a type of relative clause. I see that you have voted my answer down, and I suggest that you research the topic more thoroughly before making wild and incorrect statements the next time you do this. I often see people who get caught up in the fun of being a grammar nazi but fail to learn the rules or concepts of these things about which they are so pedantic. I have provided additional examples in my post in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: The fact remains that most native English speakers would not use the future in the sentence. We have around 10 answers to this question, all of which give different reasons why the future tense is incorrect (and I have to admit that I can't be sure my reason is the right one), but yours is the only one that actually says that the future tense is correct. It isn't, which is why I voted you down.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to figure anything out from something someone *will* send you since you don't have them yet. Putting the last part in the future tense requires you to make the first part conditional. You can do that, but it gets very awkward and verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Now that everyone's more or less knocked out the mechanics side of our conditioning in the English language, I think I'll throw my two cents in.

Your question was "Why it **sounds more natural**, yes?

Mark Twain could not stress the value of word economy and how much more effectively it preserves the clarity of the message.  Cluttering it with a twisting maze of tenses will start to fog up and the message stops being clear and concise...which is paramount in business.

All of these answers are dealing with rules on clauses and tenses, something of a nightmare to teach even natural English speakers at times...let alone someone learning it as a second language.

If your boss doesn't bite when you tell him that less is more when it comes to English then it might save everyone a lot of grief.

If he wants the rule then go ahead and refer to some of these other answers.  Hope I at least got the wheels turning

Comment: There's aesthetic appeal in brevity, sure. But English has plenty of redundancy too. You can't "explain" the usage by saying it's concise, so it must be good. Nobody except a non-native speaker doubts the prefered phrasing, but there's debate about exactly *why* we'd all use the present tense.

Comment: I was just thinking we should answer the question

Answer (score -1):

I find the existing responses a little odd and missing a rather obvious point that the implied meaning is quite different in the two sentences (they use highfalutin language to ultimately suggest "because it sounds better that way" which is tosh and piffle).

- The former example ("*from the schedules you **will** send us*") implies a reference to schedules that have not yet been sent, and presumably when you get them you may be able to figure out a solution to whatever the problem is.
- The latter example ("*from the schedules you send us*") implies that you already receive schedules from them (e.g. on a regular basis) and that you would already have the information that may be required to figure out the solution.

If you already receive schedules, and intend to use them to figure out a solution, the latter seems more appropriate. It would be reasonable for a recipient to then infer from this that you will then proceed to figure out a solution from the data you have already.

If you don't have the schedules yet, I'd use the former for clarity (the difference being in this case that the onus is clearly then on the recipient to take action and send you them, before you can proceed).

Comment: -1 That is not how a native speaker forms the conditional.   English is not a series of logical propositions it is a natural language.

Comment: "from the schedules you send us" does **not** imply they have already sent the schedules. (They have not, in fact.) To imply that, the sentence would have to be "...figure this out from the schedules you **sent** us".

Comment: Also, it's not encouraged to call other people's answers "tosh and piffle".  Even if you think it is wrong, you should show some respect in saying so.

Comment: @z7sg I am a native English speaker; I am British, as one might reasonably assume from my name, particularly my first name which uses a form uncommon in other countries. I have more than just a working command of my native language and dispute both your assertions.

Comment: @Martha, "send" in the above context does imply it's that it is a verb in the past tense it does not have to be "sent", which has another implied meaning again. In common parlance "sent" in that context could be reasonably inferred as schedules that been been sent in the past (but are no longer sent).

Comment: The "you send us" version of the sentence does indeed work for schedules which are already continuously sent, as Herr Collins says. There can be no dispute over that. His advice to avoid that form because of the ambiguity seems weaker to me, but it's definitely food for thought.