# Using "will" twice in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

Is it correct to use *will* twice in the following sentence?

> When you **will** come to see me we **will** have dinner together.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40913/why-do-i-instinctively-want-to-use-the-present-tense-with-a-conditional/

Comment: Will will will Will what Will's will's wills will will.  (William will bequeath another Willaim whatever his bequeathment's listed desires will bequeath.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no general rule against using "will" twice in the same sentence. However, your sentence is incorrect because adverbial clauses with *when* do not usually use the modal *will*. To indicate future time within a *when*-clause, use the simple present:

> When you come to see me, we will have dinner together.

Answer (score 2):

Words like *will* are often repeated for emphasis. In addition, the repeated word is often emphasized vocally:

> You *will* come to see me, we *will* have dinner, and I *will* convince you to
>   move back here.

Is that what you're thinking of? If so, you can get the same effect by dropping the first will in your sentence and emphasizing *when* instead:

> "I hope I make it back here," she said. "I'd like to see you again."
>
> "Not if, but when," I said confidently. "*When* you come to see me, we *will* have dinner together."

Comment: I don't think OP was thinking of that at all - his first "will" was just bad grammar. Your point is interesting and apposite, but I can't upvote it because you don't answer the question as I understand it.

Comment: I may well have misunderstood. In the OP's version, both *wills* are bold, so the anaphoric emphasis seemed intentional.

Comment: haha I see your point. We are indeed conditioned to have our "inner voice" place stress on words in bold/italic/quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, "Oh, when WILL you come to see me; we'll have dinner together then." but that's really stretching it. The semicolon should be a question mark, the contraction should not be used and if you want to get technical, I believe you are to substitute the word "shall" for "will" as in "Oh, when WILL you come to see me? We shall have dinner together."

Answer (score -3):

Drop the first *will* or it is just ugly, no need for the punctuation mark or the *we*. The *we* is implicit.

Comment: Are you advocating that the sentence should be *"When you come to see me will have dinner together"*? — uh, no.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *"When you come to see me we'll have dinner together"? The *we* is still there, just contracted with *will*.

Comment: Doesn't the following sentence sound better, `We will have dinner together when you come to see me`? And it also has no comma in it. :)